# Pesquisa de dados

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, arraylist

bom galera to com duvida aqui e quero fazer o seguinte em jsp eu quero que o cliente va digitar ema palavra para buscar banco de dados mysql exemplo leonardo dai eu vo ter varios nomes cadastrados do banco de dados, so que o cliente que vai pesquisar no bnco de dados ele digitou errado leotardo e nao voltou nada pq nao existe esse nome mais quero fazer algo que ele quebre todos os caracteres e faça pesquisa no banco com todas letras parecidas de uma arraylist exemplo palavras que ele digitou que tem mais de 5 palavras iguais nume array list.

String reqDescricao = request.getParameter("pesquisaNome");

```
    String descricao = "%" + reqDescricao + "%";
    EntityManagerFactory factory;
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(AbstractWebCmd.PERSITENCE_UNIT);
    AlunoDAO dao = new AlunoDAO(factory);
    List<Aluno> alunos = dao.findByDescricao(descricao);
```

to fazendo em java e jsp.

eu fiz assim mais quero mudar quero quebrar palavra em letras e quero trazer todas as palavras que tem exemplo ate 5 letras iguais no banco aguardo ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

A funcionalidade que você descreveu, de quebrar em letras e considerar até uma quantidade válida, é a descrição perfeita da implementação do algoritmo de Levenshtein.

Por exemplo, `levenshtein('Leonardo', 'Leonarto')` resulta em `1`, isto é, a distância entre *Leonardo* e *Leonarto* é uma diferença, e se você aceita até, digamos, 5 de distância de diferenças, então *Leonardo* seria uma retorno válido para a pesquisa *Leonarto*.

Neste link do Stack Overflow você encontra a implementação em Stored Procedure para MySQL desta função, que você utilizará durante a busca, dentro da clásula `WHERE` da query.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909885/how-to-add-levenshtein-function-in-mysql